# BLToolkit Output Parameter in DataAccessor

Tags: .net, bltoolkit

How to map output parameter in SQL to an out parameter in DataAccessor? I've tried to put Direction.Output attribute, but with no luck. Nonworking sample:

```
public abstract class DocumentAccessor : DataAccessor<DocumentRecord>
{
    [SprocName("[dbo].[FE_GetDocuments]")]
    public abstract IEnumerable<DocumentRecord> GetDocuments(
        [ParamName("PageIndex")] int pageIndex,
        [ParamName("PageSize")] int pageSize,
        [ParamName("SortColumn")] string sortColumn,
        [ParamName("SortDirection")] string sortDirection,
        [ParamName("TotalCount"), Direction.Output] out int totalCount);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved by changing result type to `IList<DocumentRecord>`. Looks like BLToolkit generates deferred-execution proxy for `IEnumerable<T>` signature.

Answer (score 2):

Might help

[Bltoolkit DataAccess UnitTests on Output Params](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/blob/master/UnitTests/CS/DataAccess/OutRefTest.cs)

[Bltoolkit Direction documentation](http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.DADirection.ashx)